# Angular dynamic class binding impact on perfomance

Tags: angular, performance, binding

I have an angular app with endless scroll that loads "pageSize" elements each time we scroll to the end. The list of all elements is contained in 'newsfeed' and is displayed with an *ngFor.
I need to do some processing on the displayed divs from the last range so I added a dynamic class binding as follow :

```
 <div
*ngFor="let p of newsfeed; let i = index"
[class]="i >= skip - 1.8 * pageSize ? 'new' : 'old'"> ...</div>
```

and then in typescript  I select divs with the class new.
My question is as more elements are added to the page, does the dynamic class binding above have any impact on page performance ? if yes, is there a way to measure that?

Thank you